# Proper way of using Singletons (class with structs inside) in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to understand which is the proper way of structuring my code. I have created a Singleton class for video processing (detecting silences) and storing its processing output (the silence timestamps and other info) as a Struct. As this should be a single reference in the whole program, I am using a Singleton pattern, as I will run some multithreading tasks after this one and want to have a single source of truth for that class.

```
class SilenceDetector {
  static let shared = SilenceDetector() // Singleton-pattern

  // <-- should I init it?

  func detectSilence(videoURL: URL) -> SilencesInfo { ... }

  private struct Silence {...}

  struct SilencesInfo { // <-- Should I use a Singleton-class?
   // here I run different functions with Silence struct
   ...
```

I then use SilenceDetector.shared.detectSilence() but to my surprise I cannot access SilenceDetector.shared.SilenceInfo... but SilenceDetector.SilenceInfo.

Whats the proper way of doing it?

Comment: All inner types are static by default. You can't use `SilenceDetector.shared.SilenceInfo` even if you change to a class. Maybe you want `SilenceDetector` to hold an instance of `SilencesInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper way of using the singleton pattern. It was always a hack, but has been made completely obsolete by the SwiftUI [environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment).

Your SilenceDetector should be an [EnvironmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject), whether or not you're using SwiftUI Views.

Comment: Is it a still a good practice to use Environment in big non SwiftUI / view classes ?

Comment: I say yes, because I don't expect that UIKit will ever get its own standardized environment-like solution.